# Java - My super.toString is returning null

Tags: java, tostring, super

I'm having an issue where my toString method in Department is returning null values, it seems the super.toString isn't getting the values that are inputed. I'm not sure where the code went wrong, I know it's a lot to sort through, I tried to get rid of any code that isn't important. Thanks for taking a look. Sorry if I structured this wrong.

```
public class Person {
String name;
private int age;
private String ssn;
private boolean alive;

public Person(String name, int age, String ssn, boolean alive) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.alive = alive;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + this.getName() + "\n" +
            "Age: " + this.getAge() + "\n" +
            "SSN: " + this.getSsn() + '\n' +
            "Alive: " + this.isAlive();
}
}
```

Teacher extends Person

```
public class Teacher extends Person {
private String id;
private int salary;
private int num_yr_prof;

public Teacher(String name, int age, String ssn, boolean alive,           String id, int salary, int num_yr_prof) {
    super(name, age, ssn, alive);
    this.id = id;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.num_yr_prof = num_yr_prof;
}
public Teacher(Teacher t) {
    this.id = t.id;
    this.salary = t.salary;
    this.num_yr_prof = t.num_yr_prof;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() +
            "\nID: " + getId() +
            "\nSalary: $" + getSalary() +
            "\nYears as a prof: " + getNum_yr_prof();
}
}
```

This class uses an array of teachers

```
public class Department {
private String deptName;
private int numMajors;
private Teacher[] listTeachers;

public Department(String dN, int nM, Teacher[] lT) {
    this.deptName = dN;
    this.numMajors = nM;
    this.listTeachers = new Teacher[lT.length];
    for (int i = 0; i <lT.length ; i++) {
        listTeachers[i] = new Teacher(lT[i]);
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String output = "Department: ";
    output += "\n   Name: " + getDeptName();
    output += "\n   Majors: " + getNumMajors();
    output += "\n   Teachers: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < listTeachers.length; i++) {
        output += listTeachers[i].toString(); //This is returning null values
    }
    return output;
}
}
```

The main method

```
public class lab4prt2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Teacher[] teachers = new Teacher[]{
            new Teacher(
                    "Tracy",
                    36,
                    "39890280",
                    true,
                    "4859279",
                    100000,
                    5)
    };

    Department d1 = new Department("Math", 4, teachers);

    System.out.println(d1.toString());

}
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. The `Teacher(Teacher t)` constructor doesn't invoke a super constructor, or it does (implicitly) and you haven't shown that parameterless constructor in `Person`.

Comment: In which case, what does that parameterless constructor do? I'm going to guess it doesn't initialize any of its instance fields.

Answer (score 0):

At a first look, it seems to me that the Department constructor invokes the Teacher constructor with argument Teacher.

In this constructor, the super() is not invoked, and it doesn't compile, so I guess you probably missed something during your copy paste.

Anyway, I'm afraid that this is a very inefficient code because you re-create the Teacher objects starting from your array, and above all, you're losing part of the information.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't missed anything the error made itself apparent do to the way I copied my code in. My professor wants us to recreate the the objects when calling them, he says its too hide the location of the information. Could you explain why this is inefficient?

Comment: You have a main method where you create an array of Teacher objects. Then you pass this array as an argument of the Department constructor. This object has a Teacher[], but instead of assign the passed argument to it, you re-create each object, by iterating the passed array. This means you store two times the same information that you would probably just refer to. I understand that this is probably an exercise, because in real life you would rely on a relational database, but in my opinion, there is no need to have 2 times the same instance of an immutable object.
Hope this helps :)